# Kernel space in a.out

Tags: c, linux, unix, operating-system

I am a bit confused in user space and kernel space . Is kernel space included in the 4 gb virtual memory of   a.out in linux or kernel space is different and not included in that 4 gb memory space . Also the part of 4 gb virtual memory which is reserved for operating system includes kernel or kernel space . Please do correct me if all the above concepts of me are wrong

Comment: I recently read about memory management in Linux and found this blog http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/anatomy-of-a-program-in-memory very helpfull

Comment: I am not sure "a.out" has anything to do with anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all up to the OS.

Most operating systems divide the space in 4GB like 2/2 or 3/1 because it makes it easier to switch from user mode to kernel mode, page tables are not needed to be remapped during the switch.

However, Linux even allows 4GB user space and 4GB kernel space. But as you can imagine this requires remapping the complete memory everytime you need to switch to kernel mode, which incurs some overhead.

Although it's in your memory space, OS does not allow the kernel space to be accessed from user mode code. This kind of access control is possible because of the privilege bits in the page table.

All calls to kernel from user space is actually an `int 80h` call. This call transfers the call to kernel's interrupt handler and makes both kernel and user space accessible.

Comment: +1. But Linux also allows PAE since Pentium Pro, where the kernel can address up to 64 gigabyte.

Comment: No, in PAE the kernel is not directly addressing more than 4Gb. It is just managing the maps so to use 64Gb.

Answer (score 3):

The standard memory model for 32-bit Linux uses 1 GB for the kernel, and 3 GB for the user space.

This sums to the total 4 GB memory space available, so "yes", the kernel's space is included in the address space.

[This article](http://kerneltrap.org/node/2450) has some graphs that show the split.

Comment: In fine, that means that yes, the Kernel space is included in the 4GBs of addressable virtual memory. I +1'd this answer, though it does not touch the part of the question about the OS' memory space...